# PHP DOMDocument not replacing all images in string

Tags: php, domdocument

I have a function, that should replace imgs:

```
$content    = '<img width="500" height="500" src="hhhh.jpg" /> AWDEQWE ASdAa <p>sdasdasdas</p> <img width="500" height="500" src="hhhh.jpg" /> <p>awedaweq</p>';
$document = new DOMDocument;
$document->loadHTML($content);
$imgs= $document->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
 $src= $img->getAttribute('src');
 $width= $img->getAttribute('width');
 $height= $img->getAttribute('height');
 $link= $document->createElement('a');
 $link->setAttribute('class', 'player');
 $link->setAttribute('href', $src);
 $link->setAttribute('style', "display: block; width: {$width}px; height: {$height}px;");

 $img->parentNode->replaceChild($link, $img);
}
return $document->saveHTML();
```

It works fine, but only for the first image.
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: It could be related to [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.replacechild.php#50500). When you replace the child, it changes the structure of the HTML, causing it to have only one child and having nothing else to loop.

Comment: @FirstOne Make it to an answer, so i can aceept it. :)

Comment: It's cool. I didn't really provide a solution, I just explained the problem ;).. You can post your own solution or choose the one that's available, if it works.

Answer (score 1):

The `replaceChild` method call will affect the live nodeList you are iterating over, and actually removes the node from `$imgs`. After this mutation the loop (i.e. the iterator underlying it) loses track on where it was in the original nodeList, and so the loop exits.

The solution is to first create a copy of `$imgs` into a standard array, and the loop over that:

```
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
    $images[] = $img;
}
// now proceed with the loop you really want:
foreach ($images as $img) {
    // ...etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the counter, accessing the DOMNode is dynamic. You should touch the dom element above the counter.

```
$content    = '<img width="400" height="400" src="asdf.jpg" /> AWDEQWE ASdAa <p>sdasdasdas</p> <img width="500" height="500" src="hhhh.jpg" /> <p>awedaweq</p>';
$document = new DOMDocument;
$document->loadHTML($content);
$imgs= $document->getElementsByTagName('img');
$i = $imgs->length - 1;
while ($i > -1)
{
    $node = $imgs->item($i);
 $link= $document->createElement('a');
 $link->setAttribute('class', 'player');
 $link->setAttribute('href', $node->getAttribute('src'));
 $link->setAttribute('style', "display: block; width: {$node->getAttribute('width')}px; height: {$node->getAttribute('height')}px;");

 $imgs->item($i)->parentNode->replaceChild($link, $node);
 $i--;
}
var_dump($document->saveHTML());
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it that way:

```
        $document = new DOMDocument;
        $document->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));;
        $imgs   = $document->getElementsByTagName('img');
        $i      = $imgs->length - 1; 
        while ($i > -1) { 
            $image      = $imgs->item($i); 
            $ignore     = false; 
            $width      = $image->attributes->getNamedItem('width')->value;
            $height     = $image->attributes->getNamedItem('height')->value;
            $src        = $image->attributes->getNamedItem('src')->value;
            $alt        = $image->attributes->getNamedItem('alt')->value;
            $class      = $image->attributes->getNamedItem('class')->value;
            $class      = str_replace( array( "alignleft", "alignright" ), array( "amp_alignleft", "amp_alignright" ), $class );
            $new_img    = $document->createElement('amp-img', '');
            $new_img->setAttribute('src', $src);
            $new_img->setAttribute('class', $class);
            $new_img->setAttribute('width', $width);
            $new_img->setAttribute('height', $height);
            $new_img->setAttribute('alt', $alt);
            $new_img->setAttribute('layout', 'responsive');
            $image->parentNode->replaceChild( $new_img, $image ); 
            $i--; 
        } 

        return $document->saveHTML()
```